# How to output PowerShell tree to text or Excel file

Tags: powershell, output, txt

I've the following code:

```
$readPath = "C:\FirstFolder"
$writePath = "C:\SecondFolder"

Function Recurse($folder, $lvl) {

    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$("  "*$lvl)> $($_.Name) - $((Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner)"
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "$("  "*$lvl)> $($_.Name)"
        Recurse -folder $_.FullName -lvl $($lvl+1)
    }

}

$root = Get-Item -Path $readPath
Recurse -folder $root.FullName -lvl 0
```

which gives an output like this:

```
> File0.xlsx - OwnerB
> Directory1
  >File1.1.txt - OwnerB
  >File1.2.ppt - OwnerA
>Directory2
  >File2.1 - OwnerA
  >File2.2 - OwnerA
```

When I add the code `$log | Out-File $writePath\OwnerTree.txt -Encoding UTF8`, my output file is blank.

Anyone know how to get an output file with the same layout as what appears in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few things:

1. Make your function **output** the strings instead of using `Write-Host`, of which the sole purpuse is to write to the console screen for display
2. capture the result of your function in a variable and save that to a file
3. If you want to write both to file AND to the console, use `Set-Content` instead of `Out-File`, because that also has a switch `-PassThru`

```
function Get-OwnerTree ([string]$folder, [int]$lvl) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | ForEach-Object {
        "$("  "*$lvl)> $($_.Name) - $((Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner)"
    }

    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
        "$("  "*$lvl)> $($_.Name)"
        Get-OwnerTree -folder $_.FullName -lvl (++$lvl)
    }

}

$root = Get-Item -Path $readPath
$log = Get-OwnerTree -folder $root.FullName -lvl 0

$log | Set-Content -Path "$writePath\OwnerTree.txt" -Encoding UTF8 -PassThru
```

I have also changed the function name to comply with PowerShell's [Verb-Noun](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/blob/staging/reference/docs-conceptual/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands.md) naming convention

Comment: That seems to have done the track - thank you, Theo!